# My associative array doesnt store objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

[It](http://jsfiddle.net/N2Z6Q/) seems it's always empty :

```
var idStruttura=2;
var arrayMarkers=new Array();

arrayMarkers["sede_"+idStruttura] = "ciao";
alert(arrayMarkers.length);
```

Prints always 0. Why? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array is not an associative array, however the array object is an object, and all objects are associative arrays. If you use a string as key when assigning items to the array, you are not using it as an array, you are using it as an object.

The `length` property of the array returns how many items you have stored in the array. If you also use the array object as an associative array, that won't affect how you use the array as an array.

Answer (score 2):

What you've created is a regular array object and added a property to it called `sede_...`. JavaScript doesn't use associative arrays in the same way a language like PHP does.  Arrays are objects that can have properties, but those properties are not among the numerically indexed array elements.

```
var idStruttura=2;
var arrayMarkers=new Array();

// Push an object onto the array having one property:
arrayMarkers.push({"sede_" + idStruttura : "ciao"});

// Or declare it as an object to begin with:
// This makes more sense....
var objMarkers = {};
objMarkers['sede_' + id] = 'ciao';
```

Comment: @markzzz It works because you have added a property to the array object  with that name.  It is _not_ part of the array elements such as you would iterate over with a `for (i=0; i<array.length; i++)` loop.  Arrays behave much differently in JavaScript than in PHP.

Comment: @markzzz The property you added is more similar to the `array.length` property, which contains additional information about the array.

Answer (score 2):

There is no length when you store objects, only when you use the array as intended.

Try this ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4M256/))

```
var idStruttura=2;
var arrayMarkers={}; // creates a more appropriate object than []

arrayMarkers["sede_"+idStruttura] = "ciao";
arrayMarkers["sede_"+(++idStruttura)] = "espresso";
var len = 0;
for (var o in arrayMarkers) {
    if (arrayMarkers.hasOwnProperty(o)) len++;
}
arrayMarkers.length=len
alert(arrayMarkers.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

array's in javascript (unlike php) cannot have string key's, only numeric keys. If you want a string literal as a key, please use objects

Comment: But that is not what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a simple Object, not an Array. Arrays have numeric indexes.

```
var markers = {};
markers['sede_' + id] = 'ciao';
```

Also note that `{}` is the same as `new Object()` and `[]` is the same as `new Array()`. Always use the former ones. It's much clear to any JS developer.

Comment: Yes. `Array` is also an `Object`. This is different from PHP for instance. You can set any member property of an `Array` instance but it does not affect the `length` property. Simply remember that JavaScript `Arrays` have for stuff with numeric indexes.

Comment: Uhm! So i think I can't clear this object with .lenght=0. How can i clear it?

Comment: No, you cannot. You have to loop over its keys and use the `delete` statement. `for (var key in obj) { if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) { delete obj[key]; } }`

Comment: arrayMarkers = {}; also will destroy it?

Comment: **Yes that works as well of course.** Just be sure you don't have any references to the original object somewhere else in your app.

Comment: Uhm no, it is global! I need to "destroy" it to everybody ;)

Comment: Any references to the original object will not be destroyed. If you pass the object to any other object/function, it will not know about the newly created instance. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RU46M/